# Custom dragger over seekbar of videojs player

Tags: javascript, video.js

I want to add a custom dragable button over seek bar of the videojs player, which should give the current position or timestamp of the video whenever it has been pointed somewhere over seek bar

Comment: I've done something very similar to what you describe...i.e. created my own slider just ABOVE the video-js viewer.  Demo is here:  https://weasel.firmfriends.us/Private3-BB/

Comment: Thanks for the response, But I want a simple dragger button by which can get the time of the video track, wherever I move it on the tracker. I checked there videojs API, it is very complex.

Some think like this from the UI point of view, but this old version of videojs 
http://jsfiddle.net/tmonhyjs/

Comment: My  code IS getting the time of the video track, but implicitly.  If you look closer. you'll see that my slider is in sync with video-js's progress-bar.  It's as simple as referencing 'myPlayer.currentTime()'.  (I added a line to log that value when my video gets paused... new line #350.)  It's documented under "Player.currentTime()".

Comment: I want to add that dragger over seek bar, not outside from video player. please help

Comment: Sure, just a little CSS knowledge needed.  Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371584/

Comment: But I think this will be just a hacky way, There are API's of videojs by which we can add our own markup inside the videos component. Can you please help me with that?